# css :first-letter overrides ::selection

Tags: css

When using the `:first-letter` pseudo class + `::selection` pseudo class,
the `:first-letter` overrides the custom selection color.
(seems not to be a specificity issue as changing the order maintains this behavior)

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/raz-ezra/pen/jOzmJOO) example

```css
.test::selection {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}

.test:first-letter {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class='test'>this is a test</div>
```

[RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qyd34.png)

Comment: Cannot reproduce, your snippet does not show this behaviour you specify when the selection has focus. Is that what you mean?

Comment: so I couldn't reproduce in Firefox, but I could in Chrome.

Comment: @raz-ezra if no solution is found here using CSS, you can always use JavaScript to capitalize the first letter, and only leave the selection CSS.

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi Yes, that's what I ended up doing, just wandering if this is a known thing :)